# is there a way to have .git folder in a different directory?

Tags: git, dropbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detach the local git repository from its working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495109/how-to-detach-the-local-git-repository-from-its-working-directory)

i'm trying to have that in order to integrate it with dropbox, is there a way to have this?
what i want to achieve is have a different folder not in dropbox which will store my .git so that it won't collide with different users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GIT_DIR`, .git by default, holds all the repository-specific data. You can set the `GIT_DIR` environment variable to essentially anything, even directories outside the current project.

For example, from within the root of a typical Git project:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# ...
#   modified:   config/environment.rb
```

If you move the .git directory elsewhere...

```
$ mv .git ~/my-project-git-dir
```

... Git will no longer recognize the directory itself as a Git project:

```
$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Unless you explicitly tell it where to find the Git directory for this project:

```
$ GIT_DIR=~/my-project-git-dir git status
# On branch master
# ...
#   modified:   config/environment.rb
```

Comment: so if i have multiple projects i will need to switch my env variable GIT_DIR for every project?

Comment: Yes. You need to tell Git where to find the GIT_DIR, it can't automagically find it if you move it outside the working directory.

Comment: @Jason: Or you can just not set it as an environment variable, and use  `git --git-dir <command>`.

Comment: That would be `git --git-dir=path <command>`. The two uses are functionally identical, the difference being you can set the environment variable once at the top of a script and then use `git <command>` normally.